# How to call httprequest in ajax call with playframework 1.5.0

Tags: java, ajax, httprequest, playframework-1.x

I try to call httprequest in an ajax call, but get internal error. And I know the http request call is correct beyond the ajax call. What's the problem.

Here is the code.

[image]

And the ajax call.

[image]

The error i get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the action epgProgramDetail sending an Json anonymous object:  { "programId": programId}, but in the action signature you expect a single string programId.

To unmarshall Json pass the body (untouched) as an inputStream to Gson to parse, note that you pass the pojo class representing the root to unmarshall in. Example:

```
Gson g = new Gson();  
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(request.body);  
DestinatarioDTO dto = g.fromJson(isr, DestinatarioDTO.class);
```

We use this for very complex use cases, but you can pass a Map for example if you don't want to create a class.

I guess in your case, passing the programId in the query string should be enough.

Bye, Hans